# Pandas read_csv fails silently

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to load a flat file into a python pandas data frame.
Using Python 3.8.3 and pandas version 1.0.5

The `read_csv` code is like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
df =  pd.read_csv(myfile, sep='|', usecols=[0], names=["ID"],
                    dtype=str,
                    encoding='UTF-8', 
                    memory_map=True,
                    low_memory=True, engine='c')
print('nb entries:', df["ID"].size)
```

This gives me a number of entries.
However, this does not match the number of entries I get with the following code:

```py
num_lines = sum(1 for line in open(myfile, encoding='UTF-8')
print('nb lines:', num_lines)
```

I don't get an error message.

I tried several options (with/without encoding, with/without low memory, with or without memory map, with or without warn_bad_lines, with the c engine or the default one), but I always got the same erroneous results.

By changing the `nrows` parameters I identified where in the file the problem seems to be. And I copied the lines of interest in a test file and re-run the code on the test file. This time I get the correct result.

Now I realize that my machine is a little short on memory, so maybe some allocation is failing silently. Would there be a way to test for that? I tried running the script without any other applications open, but I got the same erroneous results.

How should I troubleshoot this type of problem?

Comment: I personally would start by looking closely at the csv on a text editor and checking that the file is well formed and character escaping is correct.

Comment: Hi @GuillemB thank you for that. I could not find a problem while looking in the file. The files are relatively big (about 1 million lines), so it is not practical to go through the file. Nevertheless, I went through the lines around the problem (where the results differ between the two codes), but I could not see anything. I then copied these lines in a new file, but I did not reproduce the problem with these lines. It seems to work fine when the file is small.

Comment: How about using `nrows` and `skiprows` in conjunction within a for a loop. On each iteration you save the read lines into a file (e.g. parquet)? That way you can control more finely how much memory you are using.

If at the end the sum of the rows within the generated files matches `wc -l mycsv.csv` then likely the problem is with memory.

Comment: Sounds good. I will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could be used to read the file in chunks

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n_rows = sum(1 for _ in open("./test.csv", encoding='UTF-8')) - 1
chunk_size = 300
n_chunks = int(np.ceil(n_rows / chunk_size))


read_lines = 0
for chunk_idx in range(n_chunks):
    df = pd.read_csv("./test.csv", header=0, skiprows=chunk_idx*chunk_size, nrows=chunk_size)
    read_lines += len(df)

print(read_lines)
```

Comment: This was helpful in finding the problem in the file. In the end I moved to numpy and did: ``` np.loadtxt(myfile, dtype=str, delimiter='|', encoding='UTF-8', usecols=0) ``` and it works. I got the hexadecimal of the line causing issue in pandas but could not find the problem.

Comment: Would it be possible to share that line if there is no sensitive information in it or it can be anonymized?

Comment: unfortunately not :( 
I tried to compare the hexadecimal characters from this line to other lines, but nothing stood out. Because the hexadecimal also relied on python, I also tried to get the hex from Powershell. In both cases nothing to report. Anyway, the loadtxt works fine, so I won't spend more time on this.